# Calling getCollection in phtml is empty

Tags: magento2, blocks, product-collection, phtml, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5, I am setting the Block for phtml using below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head></head>
<body>
<attribute name="class" value="account"/> 
   <referenceBlock name="left.permanent.callout" remove="true"/>
   <referenceBlock name="right.permanent.callout" remove="true"/>
   <referenceBlock name="cart_sidebar" remove="true"/>
   <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
   <referenceBlock name="right.poll" remove="true"/>
   <referenceBlock name="tags_popular" remove="true"/>
   <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
   <referenceContainer name="page.top">
       <container name="topnavigation" as="topnavigation" label="Top Navigation" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="topnavigation">
             <block class="Mymodule\Namespace\Block\Navigation\Top" name="page.main.topnavigation" template="Magento_Theme::html/navigation/top.phtml"/>
          </container>
    </referenceContainer>
   <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
     <block class="Mymodule\Namespace\Block\Listings\Sidebar" name="sidebar.manage.listings" template="namespace/listings/sidebar.phtml" before="airhotels_listings_manage"/>
   </referenceContainer>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
     <block class="Mymodule\Namespace\Block\Listings\Manage" name="airhotels_listings_manage" template="Mymodule_Namespace::namespace/listings/manage.phtml" />
   </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

I am using the below code in Block function:

```
    <?php

namespace Mymodule\Namespace\Block\Listings;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry;
use Zend\Form\Annotation\Object;

/**
 * This class used to display the products collection
 */
class Manage extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    /**
     * Initilize variable for product factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;
    protected $_currency;
    /**
     * Initilize variable for stock registry
     *
     * @var Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry
     */
    protected $stockRegistry;
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     *
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, Collection $productFactory, \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency, StockRegistry $stockRegistry, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager, array $data = []) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_currency = $currency;
        parent::__construct ( $context, $data );
    }

    /**
     * Set product collection uisng ProductFactory object
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct() {
        parent::_construct ();
        $collection = $this->getFilterProducts ();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare layout for manage product
     *
     * @return object $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        parent::_prepareLayout ();
        /**
         *
         * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager
         */
        $pager = $this->getLayout ()->createBlock ( 'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager', 'namespace.product.list.pager' );
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(
                10 => 10,
                20 => 20,
                50 => 50
            ))->setShowAmounts ( false )->setCollection ($this->getCollection ());
        $this->setChild ( 'pager', $pager );
        $this->getCollection () ->load();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Manage product pager html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPagerHtml() {
        return $this->getChildHtml ( 'pager' );
    }

    /**
     * Product filter
     *
     * @return Object
     */
    public function getFilterProducts() {


        /**
         * Filter by product attributes
         */

        $product = $this->productFactory->addAttributeToSelect ( '*' )->addAttributeToFilter ( 'user_id', $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId () );
        $product->addAttributeToFilter ( 'visibility', array (
                'eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH
        ) );
        $product->addAttributeToSort ( 'entity_id', 'DESC' );

        /**
         * Return product object
         */
        return $product;
    }
    }
```

In phtml file I am calling the `setCollection` function as below:

```
  $products = $this->getCollection();//I tried this too: $block->getCollection();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($products);
    exit;
```

But it not prints anything. Is there any mistakes in this code. please help me to sort out this.

Comment: Try to remove the `'user_id'` filter and check is anything changing? Additionally, you can check sql using the `$sql = $this->getCollection()->getSelectSql(true);
        var_dump($sql);` code.

Comment: Can you please add your phtml file in question

Comment: @RutveeSojitra I added the phtml content at last already. pls check it. Its just `print_r($this->getCollection());`.